# Elixir Explorer - DataFrame cast string to time

Tags: elixir

I try to cast an Explorer.Series row from a string to a Time type.

The DataFrame.mutate function won't allow me to transform to a different type. Should I combine this Series.transform with a Series.cast?

```
df = Explorer.DataFrame.from_map(%{a: ["00:30:00", "01:00:00", "05:30:00"]})

transform_duration = fn duration ->
   time = Time.from_iso8601!(duration)
   time.hour + (time.minute / 60) + (time.second / 60*60)
end


DataFrame.mutate(df, a: Series.transform(s, fn x -> transform_duration.(x) end))
```

Maybe my whole approach ain't good?

The above code snippet returns me this error:

```
** (ArgumentError) cannot parse "this " as time, reason: :invalid_format
    (elixir 1.13.2) lib/calendar/time.ex:281: Time.from_iso8601!/2
    (stdlib 3.17) erl_eval.erl:685: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (stdlib 3.17) erl_eval.erl:446: :erl_eval.expr/5
    (stdlib 3.17) erl_eval.erl:123: :erl_eval.exprs/5
    (elixir 1.13.2) lib/enum.ex:1593: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (explorer 0.1.0-dev) lib/explorer/polars_backend/series.ex:385: Explorer.PolarsBackend.Series.transform/2
```

Comment: What is the expected result vs. your actual result?

Comment: Good question, it gives me an error. I edited the question.

Comment: Haven't done anything with Explorer yet, but other nx parts like to bleed compiler errors into the variables - try inspecting what actually ends up in your data frame, the error message says it contains `this `, thats certainly none of your values there

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `Explorer.Dataframe.put/3`:

```
Explorer.DataFrame.put(df, "a", Explorer.Series.transform(df["a"], fn x -> transform_duration.(x) end))

#Explorer.DataFrame<
  Polars[3 x 1]
  a float [0.5, 1.0, 5.5]
>
```